# How to store a particular key value from a list of dictionaries in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have been trying to store the values of a particular key into a  pandas data frame from another data frame having list of dictionaries.
Can anyone help me how to do that??

[source data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lscCY.png)

[result data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tVv9.png)

Answer (score 0):

transpose the dataframe and use loc to replace the column values with dictionary values by index lookup.

```
dct2={0:[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}] ,
     1:[{'a':4,'b':5},{'a':4,'b':1}] ,
     2:[{'a':3,'b':6},{'a':5,'b':4}] 
    }
df=pd.DataFrame(dct2)
df=df.T
df=df.rename(columns={0:'a^',1:'b^'})
df=df.reset_index()
print(df)

for key,row in df.iterrows():
     df.loc[key,'a^']=str(row['a^']['a'])+","+str(row['b^']['a'])
    df.loc[key,'b^']=str(row['a^']['b'])+","+str(row['b^']['b'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out the following code -

```
# assuming that source data frame is df and you have imported pandas as pd
dataDict = {'a': [], 'b': []}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    dataDict['a'].append((row[0][0]['a'], row[0][1]['a']))
    dataDict['b'].append((row[0][0]['b'], row[0][1]['b']))
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(dataDict)
print(newDataFrame)
```

Comment: It is throwing an error: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: the solution is to create tuples in a list and then build the dataframe.

Comment: @ParashantMahajan Then you have implemented or posted wrong code. Moreover, someone has downvoted me unjustified !! The attribute error is showing that you have a series object in df while I have mentioned explictly in the top most comment that I am assuming it to be a dataframe as per your question!!